# Removing 1 connected smoke detector ok?

Tags: smoke-detectors

We have a 2 story house that currently has the following interconnected Firex smoke detectors:

- Basement
- First Floor
- Second Floor
- Unfinished Attic

We've been having issues with the one in the unfinished attic and it seems the more I read, you don't need a smoke detector in an attic. We are in NH so it gets well below 40F and well above 100F in the attic.

My question is:  can I just remove (unplug) the attic smoke detector and leave the quick connect plug in place in the ceiling without that affecting the other smoke detectors?  Or does that unused wiring need to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Detectors are not daisy-chained, but wired in parallel and can be individually disabled or have new ones added.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I kind of figured that since the others still work fine when testing but wanted to make sure.

Comment: The one in the attic may have been going off from dust. + agree with Isherwood this will not be a problem.